# Why is it fine to use Boost.Intrusive containers to store polymorphic objects?

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism

It is an often repeated piece of advice that one should not inherit from classes with non-virtual destructor (if the intention is to use dynamic polymorphism). This is why inheriting from standard container classes is considered a bad idea.

On the other hand, Boost.Intrusive explicitly [states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage_when.html) that its containers are suitable for storing polymorphic objects. In the example from the link, this is achieved by deriving from `boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>` which does not have a virtual destructor and only introducing one in the derived class.

1. Is this a valid design?
2. If so, why and how does it fit the general advice I mentioned above? I particular, why wouldn't the same logic justify inheriting from standard containers?

(Note that my question is not about differences between standard containers and Boost.Intrusive containers. I am interested in correct usage of Boost.Intrusive, but I mention standard containers only as an example since they often come up when similar topics are discussed.)

Answer (score 2):

One should not inherit from classes with non-virtual destructor only if the use of derived classes involves ownership of objects via a pointer to a base class. There is nothing special about standard container classes. Inheriting from them is not necessary a bad idea, but the thing is that other approaches of extending their functionality should be preferred: adding a stand-alone function or aggregation.

Deriving from `boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>` is a totally valid design because ownership of derived objects is never held via a pointer to `list_base_hook`. Note that library offers hooking through aggregation (using   `list_member_hook`) which should be preferred to inheritance.

Comment: Ownership via base class pointer *and polymorphic destruction*. `std::shared_ptr`, for example, type-erases and stores the pointee's destructor upon construction, and thus does not need a virtual destructor to work.

Comment: @Quentin Unfortunately there is no magic in `shared_ptr`, it is only capable of properly taking ownership over a pointers to a derived class object. `Base * const naked_p_base{new Derived{}}; ::std::shared_ptr<Base> p_base{naked_p_base};` is broken unless `Base` destructor is virtual or an appropriate deleter is supplied.

Comment: Of course, but I did say "upon construction" -- as always in C++ you can go out of your way to break stuff, but if you just use `std::make_unique` like a civilized person everything will be fine :)

Comment: I am aware of member hooks. Why do you say that they should be preferred to base hooks? The documentation doesn't say anything like that as far as I can see. Indeed, the last paragraph under "Using member hooks" [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage.html) seems to say the exact opposite, especially in the context of polymorphism.

Comment: @VTT Regarding that member hooks should be preferred to base hooks, that's not actually true. Member hooks require non-portable implementation in Boost.Intrusive, and while for most widespread compilers the working implementation is provided (search for `offset_from_pointer_to_member`), it is still not portable and may break in some cases. Base hooks don't have this problem and should be portable.

Comment: @AndreySemashev This is a valid point, however it is rather a question of proper implementation.

Comment: @RobertE.Brown The same paragraph names the primary reason to use member hooks in the first sentence: *"Sometimes an 'is-a' relationship between list hooks and the list value types is not desirable"*. And *sometimes* should rather be *usually* because `is-a` is a strongest possible relationship kind. Another motivation to use member hooks is that they tend to simplify things when class contains multiple hooks and won't clutter class public interface.

Comment: @VTT The mere concept of having the hook as a member does not allow a portable implementation. There is no way in C++ to translate a pointer to member to a pointer to the containing object.

Comment: @VTT: _public_ inheritance expresses an `is-a` relation. Private inheritance does not.